# Cumulative product using input from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a combination of some daily return estimates and month-to-day (MTD) returns, which are issued weekly. I want to combine these two data series to get a daily estimated MTD value.

I have tried to summarize what I would like to archieve below

[image]

I got all the columns except MTD_estimate, which I would like to derive from DailyReturnEstimate and MTD. In case that a MTD value exist, then it should use that value. Otherwise, it should do a cumulative product of the returns. My code looks as follows

```
select *, exp(sum(log(1+DailyReturnEstimate)) OVER (ORDER BY dates) )-1 as Cumu_DailyReturn from TestTbl
```

My problem is that I am not sure how to do use the MTD value when present when doing the cumulative product.

I am using Microsot SQL 2012. I have made a small data example below:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTbl (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  dates date,
  DailyReturnEstimate float,
  MTD integer,
);

INSERT INTO TestTbl
(id, Dates, DailyReturnEstimate, MTD) VALUES
(1, '2020-01-01', -0.01, NULL  ),
(2, '2020-01-02', 0.005 , NULL  ),
(3, '2020-01-03', 0.012 , NULL  ),
(4, '2020-01-04', -0.007 , NULL ),
(5, '2020-01-05', 0.021 , 0.016  ),
(6, '2020-01-06', 0.001 , NULL  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, but the idea is to set up separate groups based on where `mtd` is already defined.  Then do the calculation only within those groups:

```
select t.*,
       exp(sum(log(1+coalesce(mtd, DailyReturnEstimate))) OVER (partition by grp ORDER BY dates) )-1 as Cumu_DailyReturn
from (select t.*,
             count(mtd) over (order by dates) as grp
      from testtbl t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c6b1ee90c1129eedf7ca236538cb1c6) is a db<>fiddle.